# Setuid command seems to not working

Tags: linux, setuid

I had windows application installed on Linux Mint computer, for example, in Demo directory. And in Demo folder, I have files directories structure as follow

```
  -rwxrwxrwx spuser spuser aaa.dll 
  -rwxrwxrwx spuser spuser bbb.ttf 
  -rwxrwxrwx spuser spuser ccc.ref 
  -rwsrwxrwx spuser spuser DemoApp.EXE <= I've set setuid command on this file
  drwxrwxrwx spuser spuser icons
  drwxrwxrwx spuser spuser secure
  drwxrwxr-- spuser spuser lang
```

If I run DemoApp.EXE with spuser privilege, it work fine, DemoApp.EXE can read files within lang directory. But when I run DemoApp.EXE with ordinary user privilege, it have error that say cannot read files within lang directory that I set it read-only for others (as above directories structure). I try to run both in Linux mint with WINE or run this program on Windows pc, it have same result.

Please advise me, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Cross-posted at Unix:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127204/setuid-command-seems-to-not-working

Comment: This is also cross-posted at StackOverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283251/setuid-seem-to-not-working

Answer (score 0):

In order to read a file in a directory the executable bit "x" on the directory must be set.

so far only spuser, and members of spuser group can dive into the directory.

just check it with `cd lang` when you are the different user.

chmod o+rx lang will fix it.

Comment: Thank for your reply, mestia. 

And yes, when I use command chmod o+rx on 'lang' directory, the DemoApp.exe can run correctly, but it also make other can read on this directory too. I would like others cannot read or access this directory except DemoApp.exe only.